# Why are Updates Disabled by Administrator?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, updates

As per above heading, the question is why. The PC is running fine, no issues and up to date on the current version of Chrome (40.0.2214.111 dev-m).

Using run: gpedit.msc 'Windows cannot find file'. Cannot open ADM template. However, I most likely can change the value key in the registry to 1 from 0 to enable update. This issue may have occurred when uninstalling Symantec Endpoint due to definitions expiring. New security (M.S.E.) boots up the PC much faster and works well.

Is this a cause of concern, and will Chrome continue to update in the present configurable mode, "Updates disabled by administrator"? It does appear that Chrome has recently updated on Feb. 10, 2015 but I am unsure as to when this issue started. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is this computer managed by an IT department? Or your own personal machine?

Comment: Not IT managed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the reason that updates were disabled:

Some anti-malware suites lock down automatic updates of common software such as browsers to prevent attack through ersatz "updates". Check *Symantec Endpoint* for information. As you suspect, *Symantec Endpoint* is most likely **not completely uninstalled**. See [Uninstall Symantec Endpoint Protection](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=tech184988), [How do I uninstall Symantec EndPoint Protection (SEP) anti-virus from my computer??](https://kb.berkeley.edu/page.php?id=41584) and other sites for information on *the particular version of the AV* you had installed. BTW, I do not recommend running without any AV -- there are a number of effective free tools, such as Avast!, Bitdefender and Kaspersky, that do not greatly slow the startup and that can avoid a *great* deal of grief. See [The Best Free Antivirus for 2015](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2388652,00.asp).

In a corporate environment there is often an *approved* version of software to reduce incompatibilities amongst the machines and to reduce the risk of installation of malicious software. In that case, do not expect an automatic update; contact the IT department if you think it's a concern.

Comment: 1. M.S.E. has AV. I am in unison by suites locking down auto updates. However, when Endpoint was installed, there were no issues. The latter part of your answer does not apply to my issue but your theory is correct. I did go to the Reg to rid traces of Symantec Endpoint but the values are joined with the 'default'. I wish not to erase or eliminate the default key. Symantec traces in the Reg are harmless and will not affect the update section to my knowledge.

Comment: 2.  What is your opinion on changing the Reg Key in policies to 1 from 0? I would only believe that this would be a viable option. However, the latest version (Stable version of Chrome) is up to date. Do you believe that being in this configurable mode, "Windows Update Disabled by Administrator" that Chrome will still update via Google?  I am well aware of the security suites you mentioned, as well as uninstalling Symantec. If you have some time, please reply to the questions posed. I did not receive an email to this thread.

Comment: 3. It may very well be that M.S.E. may, 'may' have locked down the updates. I really cannot acquire that information through Microsoft Security Essentials. We hope that Microsoft and Google are on talking terms. Thank you very much for your assistance. I'll play it out and see what happens. My personal opinion, Google is still in control.